# Print command doesn't work how it should be in python

Tags: python

Can anyone help me out what I did wrong. So i need to print out the name read from file in a column of list like this:

admin

admin

admin

....

admin

But my code keep printing out the name sideways like this:

['admin', 'admin', 'admin', 'admin', 'admin']

Any help would really appreciate.

```
# Define a function

def parse_file():
    users = []
    filename = "auth.log"
    file = open(filename, 'r')
    string = "invalid user"

# Parsing auth.log file, detect invalid users, sort them and return the result

    for i in file:
        i = i.lower()
        pos = i.find(string)
        if pos >= 0:
            index = pos + len(string) + 1
            user = i[index:].split(" ")[0]
            users.append(user)
    users.sort()
    return users


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(parse_file( ))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The print command works as it should. It prints a list of strings.

You probably want to do the following

```
>>> l = ['admin', 'admin', 'admin', 'admin', 'admin']
>>> print('\n'.join(l))
admin
admin
admin
admin
admin
```

See [`str.join(iterable)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) for the function that was "missing".

Answer (score 2):

It is just printing your users list. A list has the form of ['a', 'b', ...] You can just do:

```
for x in parse_file():
    print(x)
```